# How to check if a web-service is REST or SOAP?

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, soap

Could anyone please let me know how we can check if a particular web-service is REST or SOAP?

I understand that the main difference is the wsdl file, however, even for WCF REST service with webHttpBinding, one has a wsdl file which is generated.

I want to know the best possible ways to identify for a given service, check if it is a REST or SOAP.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a practical purpose here? Is there something specific you want to know about a given service?

Comment: The big clue is that you have to send SOAP messages to a SOAP service...

Comment: I have a similar question ! Suppose we have only webService URI how can we figure out if its REST or SOAP based ?

Answer (score 3):

Check for WSDL definition. If exists the web service is SOAP. By convention the WSDL file is located on following URL: [webservice_url]?wsdl

P.S. This check will work in most cases, but not all cases. REST web services sometimes are described with WADL (https://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/)